# How can I get a single marker to update it's position as the user moves in GMap.net

Tags: c#

```
string lat = "40.682640,40.682671,40.682701,40.682732,40.682763,40.682794";
string lng = "-73.868470,-73.868359,-73.868247,-73.868136,-73.868025,-73.867913";
int index = 0;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
    MyTimer.Interval = (2000);
    MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
    MyTimer.Start();
} 
private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string[] Latitude = lat.Split(',');
    string[] Longitude = lng.Split(',');

    gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.BingMapProvider.Instance;
    GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
    GMapProvider.WebProxy = null;
    gmap.SetPositionByKeywords("Atlantic Ave,USA");
    gmap.Position = new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(40.683377, -73.865798);
    gmap.ShowCenter = false;
    GMapOverlay markers = new GMapOverlay("markers");
    GMapMarker marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(float.Parse(Latitude[index]), float.Parse(Longitude[index])), GMarkerGoogleType.blue);

    gmap.Overlays.Add(markers);
    markers.Markers.Add(marker);
    index++;

    GMapMarker marker1 = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(40.684175, -73.862904), GMarkerGoogleType.green);

    markers.Markers.Add(marker1);
}
```

I need to get a single marker update its position (blue marker) as the user moves while the other marker remains stationary. I've tried  `markers.Markers.remove(marker);` but all markers are being removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the single marker update its position when i declared the marker outside the MyTimer_Tick method

```
    string lat = "40.682640,40.682671,40.682701,40.682732,40.682763,40.682794,40.682824,40.682855,40.682886,40.682916,40.682947,40.682978,40.683008,40.683039,40.683070,40.683101,40.683131,40.683162,40.683193,40.683223,40.683254,40.683285,40.683316,40.683346,40.683377,40.683408,40.683438,40.683469,40.683500,40.683530,40.683561,40.683592,40.683623,40.683653,40.683684,40.683715,40.683745,40.683776,40.683807,40.683838,40.683868,40.683899,40.683930,40.683960,40.683991,40.684022,40.684053,40.684083,40.684114,40.684145,40.684175";
    string lng = "-73.868470,-73.868359,-73.868247,-73.868136,-73.868025,-73.867913,-73.867802,-73.867691,-73.867579,-73.867468,-73.867357,-73.867246,-73.867134,-73.867023,-73.866912,-73.866800,-73.866689,-73.866578,-73.866466,-73.866355,-73.866244,-73.866132,-73.866021,-73.865910,-73.865798,-73.865687,-73.865576,-73.865464,-73.865353,-73.865242,-73.865130,-73.865019,-73.864908,-73.864797,-73.864685,-73.864574,-73.864463,-73.864351,-73.864240,-73.864129,-73.864017,-73.863906,-73.863795,-73.863683,-73.863572,-73.863461,-73.863349,-73.863238,-73.863127,-73.863015,-73.862904";
    int index = 0;

    GMapOverlay markers = new GMapOverlay("markers");
    GMapMarker marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(40.682640, -73.868470), GMarkerGoogleType.blue);

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer MyTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        MyTimer.Interval = (1000);
        MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
        MyTimer.Start();    //calling the timer
    }

    private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        //adding google map
        string[] Latitude = lat.Split(',');
        string[] Longitude = lng.Split(',');
        gmap.MapProvider = BingMapProvider.Instance;
        GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
        GMapProvider.WebProxy = null;
        gmap.SetPositionByKeywords("Atlantic Ave,USA");
        gmap.Position = new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(40.683377, -73.865798);
        gmap.ShowCenter = false;
        gmap.Overlays.Add(markers);
        markers.Markers.Add(marker);  //adding the blue marker
        index++;
        marker.Position = new PointLatLng(float.Parse(Latitude[index]), float.Parse(Longitude[index]));
        GMapMarker marker1 = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(40.684175, -73.862904), GMarkerGoogleType.green);
        markers.Markers.Add(marker1);  //adding the green marker 
    }
```

But the map is getting redrew after every few seconds.Is there any way to download the map and use it offline so that the redrawing of the map is avoided.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source code](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMapMarker.cs), something like the following should update the position:

```
marker.Position = new PointLatLng(lat, lng);
```

`GMarkerGoogle` inherits from `GMapMarker` which has a `public PointLatLng Position`. The setter of `Position` is like so:

```
set
{
    if(position != value)
    {
        position = value;
        if(IsVisible)
        {
            if(Overlay != null && Overlay.Control != null)
            {
                Overlay.Control.UpdateMarkerLocalPosition(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the `Overlay.Control.UpdateMarkerLocalPosition(this);`

Comment: I tried this but didn't work.The marker is not being updated @Jaun Ferrer

Comment: Well, there are three conditions before `UpdateMarkerLocalPosition`. If it's visible, it's either `Overlay` or `Overlay.Control` being null.